# Why does "return;" skip iterations in $.each()?

Tags: jquery

[MDN on the return statement:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

> The expression to return. If omitted, undefined is returned instead.

[jQuery docs on $.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

> Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.

Since `undefined` evaluates to `false`, why are iterations being skipped below?

```
$.each([1,2,3], function(k, v){
    if(v > 1)
        return;
    console.log(v); //1
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XYzd9/)

Comment: In my console output is displays `1`. If this isn't as expected (by you), what do you expect to be displayed?

Comment: Your question would be better demonstrated by something like `if (v<2)` -- [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/XYzd9/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's what the `.each` function is designed to do. It tests for *strict* equality to `false`. From the [source code](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.each):

```
    for (; i < length; i++) {
        value = callback.apply(obj[i], args);
        if (value === false) { 
            break;
        }
    }
```

As the docs say: If you `return` with any other value, the callback function will simply stop where you return. If you `return false` -- and only `false` -- it aborts the entire thing.

Comment: This is what I wanted to know. I would say that the term "non-false" is a bit missleading in the docs. Thanks

Comment: The [bug reporting site](http://bugs.jquery.com/) says: "jQuery Core API Documentation issues: Problems with the documentation should be reported to [api.jquery.com GitHub repository](http://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues). Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

No iterations are being skipped. You only output the value if it is greater than `1`. `2` and `3` are both greater than `1` so their values are not logged so you see no output for those values in the array.

Comment: If no iterations are being skipped, why does this log `1` and not `3`? http://jsfiddle.net/XYzd9/2/

Comment: @Johan Because `count++` is only reached in the first case; in the other two iterations, the function terminates before it is reached. If you move `count++` to the *top* of the function, you'll see `3`: http://jsfiddle.net/XYzd9/4/.

Comment: @Johan [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XYzd9/3/) with some more console outputs may make things make more sense.

Comment: @ajp15243 Thanks for elaborating. But since I placed my if statement above in the very beginning of the callback, I would still say that it skips iterations (even though it technically doesn't, proved by your example). But I guess it comes down to how you look at it :)

Comment: @Johan It's more a case of your callback function (passed to `$.each`) returning before your `count++;` statement can even execute. It's like having a state check at the top of a function to exit early if the state is bad; the rest of the code in that function will not execute. The behavior has nothing to do with `$.each`. However, your original question that utilized `return;` (impled `undefined`) instead of `return true;` like your second fiddle is obviously answered by Blazemonger's answer, which additionally *does* have to do with `$.each`'s behavior (tho it still returns early).